# Chrome notice the cert is not safe signed by third party

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

I generate a ssl cert by third party for free signed by Symentic. Here is the config of my nginx:

```
server {
        listen 8088;
        server_name wxtest.laxalex.net
        ssl on;

ssl_certificate /srv/wqd_wx_miniapp_test_ssh/server.crt;

ssl_certificate_key /srv/wqd_wx_miniapp_test_ssh/server.key;

ssl_session_timeout 5m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4:!DHE;

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
root /srv/wqd_wx_miniapp_test;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

The paths of site's root, the .crt and .key are correct.

When I open the page `https://wxtest.laxalex.net:8088` in chrome, the page shows

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

And the Security inspector shows

```
This page is not secure.
Certificate - valid and trusted
The connection to this site is using a valid, trusted server certificate issued by 未知名称(**in engish : unknown name **).
Resources - all served securely
All resources on this page are served securely.
```

Is the config wrong or the cert invalid.

You can access the page for more information `https://wxtest.laxalex.net:8088`.

PS. The cert is signed in China mainland and the server is in Hongkong. Is the region matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot semicolon at end of `server_name`.